# Getting the value at the end of a long chain of registry entries

Tags: vb.net, registry

This is my first attempt to use the registry in any depth, so bear with me...

I write small VB.net programs that interact with Excel and other programs to produce complex reports. As part of this we sometimes have to interact with a 3rd party DLL. Since this DLL is generally very rare, we took an "always install" policy, and run their installer on first-start.

Well now we have a customer who already has the 3rd party app, so the install fails (as it should). But this leaves me trying to find where the DLL/app has been installed so I can call it properly. Poking about in regedit (causing it to repeatedly crash) I have found it seems to be like this...

Installing the DLL produces an entry called `APLW.WSEngine` in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, as well as an apparently identical copy in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\`. Those entries both contain a `CLSID` which can be found in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\[the key]\TypeLib` as well as entries for a variety of sub-parts of the install. I also find it at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\[the key]`, and here it has a key called `\3.0\HELPDIR\` that contains the directory I'm looking for.

So...

What is the minimum number of calls I need to make to find the value in that `HELPDIR` key, or get `Nothing` or `""` if any of the keys doesn't exist. In the end I either need that path, or nothing if the software has not been installed. Currently I'm making repeated calls into the reg to look up each entry and key in turn, but I suspect there is a way to chain them?

To make things *slightly* more complex, that `\3.0\` in the path may change, the actual value is in the `Version` key in the original `CLSID` entry. If there is an easy way to add this I'll use it, but since we only work with 3.0 (AFAIK) it can be ignored.

Comment: Could whoever down voted this take a few seconds and indicate why, so I can improve my question next time?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe 1.  Maybe more.  Don't know, this was not a very typically laid out question (which is probably why you got down voted), but I'm going to assume that you are more of a numbers / reporting person than a software engineer.  So proceeding with that assumption, I will try and be helpful instead of pointing out any breaches of etiquette and provide you a couple resources that may help.

For starters, how to read a registry value:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz88758e.aspx

Secondly, the full tech spec on the Registry class in vb.net:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry(v=vs.110).aspx

Both give plenty of samples that should aid you along your way. But keep in mind that in certain situations and certain computer setups, these sorts of registry calls might require you to elevate your UAC permissions, if you run into such a case, you can try this resource, which covers in some detail how to make your applications UAC aware:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17968/Making-Your-Application-UAC-Aware

I hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: Can you be more detailed on what you mean by "not very typically laid out"? I tried to provide my steps, my progress, and my question.

Comment: Well, if you look at the tooltip provided, a down-vote means that the person did not show any research effort, or the question is confusing, or if the question is not useful.  In my opinion you clearly knew what you need to do, and a well formed google query would have landed you on any of the 3 links that I provided you.   Plus with the information being that readily available then makes the "usefulness" of this question redundant, as the questions have been answered already.   The confusing part might be a factor too, as it is very wordy.

Comment: Ahh, I have never seen that feature before. That is useful!

Comment: Wait how do you see the tooltip?